# A Reverse Right Angle Pyramid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment that requires me to print an upside down text pyramid in Python. I know how to print out a right angle pyramid but how do I flip it? This is what I have for the right angle pyramid:

```
try:

  us = input("Enter a short sentence: ")

except:
  print("Incorrect Input.")
  continue

else:
  for index in range(len(text)): 
    print(*text[:index + 1])
```

But I want to print something like this:

```
e x a m p l e
e x a m p l 
e x a m p
e x a m
e x a
e x
e
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `print(*text[:-index])`

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the loop indices to count down instead of up:

```
  for index in reversed(range(len(text))): 
    print(*text[:index + 1])
```

Comment: I guess this one will flip the pyramid upside-down

Answer (score 0):

you can simple write like this

```
try:

  us = input("Enter a short sentence: ")

except:
  print("Incorrect Input.")
  continue

else:
  for index in range(len(text)): 
    print(*text[:len(text) - index])
```

just have make the factor **index + 1** to **len(text) - index**

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease `index` in your `for` loop.  Right now you're increasing it:

```
text = 'example'
for index in range(len(text),0,-1): 
    print(*text[:index])
```

Output:

```
e x a m p l e
e x a m p l
e x a m p
e x a m
e x a
e x
e
```